# What are the limitations of the let command?

Tags: shell, limits, let

I'm curious about the limitations of the `let` command in a shell; I've tried searching for information but unfortunately it's a very common word and it's a shell built-in so many man pages don't actually describe what it does.

I have however been using it a lot for basic arithmetic operations, but for larger values I'm concerned about whether `let` may have limitations that might result in issues later on. I know `bc` is intended to handle arbitrary precision values, and I prefer to use it if I know it's going to be available, but some platforms I'm working with don't have it. My inclination is to convert code feeding values into `bc` to instead use `let`, but how limited is it? For example, does it work in a specific width of integer, and is this platform specific? If relevant, I'd also like to know if `let` has any common non-standard features or variations, so I can avoid using these.

Basically what I'm hoping for in an answer is a summary of any limitations on values that `let` can work with, and what features of it are specific to platforms or architecture features that it runs upon.

Comment: you may end up with a better answer on ServerFault or Unix&Linux

Comment: Do your platforms have 1. python, which uses arbitrary precision ints? 2. perl, which has them with 'use bigint'? 3. ruby, which uses them by default?  There must be some common tool that is in the intersection of your platforms.  I would never trust bash to do significant arithmetic.

Comment: @Sean I wouldn't call it significant, only that I expect values edging towards the limit for a 32-bit value, and probably shouldn't be targeting 64-bit only architectures. Unfortunately the platforms I'm working with include network attached storage systems, which don't have python, perl or ruby installed as standard, and I'm trying to avoid having to bundle anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you define larger values, your concerns are valid.

Let does "fixed with" integer aritmethics with no overflow checking whatsoever, the "fixed width" is implementation/system dependent.  I do not know if posix defines the a minimum "width". If I recall correctly, bash does the calculations using longs.

Note on protability; Korn, bash and POSIX compatible shells have let, older bourne shells do not.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! In that case I may have to do some custom multiplication with several let commands, fortunately I've worked with big integer implementations elsewhere, but annoyingly portability is the biggest requirement; `let` does seem to have enough availability fortunately, I don't think I need to worry about older bourne shells.